# How to use actual file path in file system using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, filesystems

I am sending file from client to server so i can read content , so when i try to upload file i am getting error `cannot read property`, i am scratching my head for hours but could not find solution. Looks like path issue any idea how can resolve this problem ?

server.js

```
export function create(req, res) {
 data.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path,'utf8');
     res.json(fileContent   );
    });
```

console.log(files.file)

```
[ { fieldName: 'file',
originalFilename: 'sco_poc.bpmn',
path: 'C:\\Users\\529u\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\R8CtG_jsOxhkEvYiGlfsGolM.bpmn',
headers:
 { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="sco_poc.bpmn"',
   'content-type': 'application/octet-stream' },
size: 11078 } ]
```

error

```
sers\sh529u\modeler\modeler\server\api\fileUpload\fileUpload.controller.js:14
    var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path, 'utf8');
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at C:/modeler/server/api/fileUpload/fileUpload.controller.js:7:46
    at C:\Users\sh529u\modeler\modeler\node_modules\multiparty\index.js:129:9
    at C:\Users\sh529u\modeler\modeler\node_modules\multiparty\index.js:108:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Comment: Can you console.log(files.file); and post your result ?

Comment: what type of object is 'files'?

Comment: @hussain try using files[0] instead of files.file[0]
Example can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

Comment: @Dylan if i use f`iles[0]` i got this error `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: @hussain could you give more information about the variables ? Try just console.log(files) and console.log(files[0]) to find out the outcome if you're trying to access 'files[0].path' and its saying 'path' is not defined. Make sure what you're getting is a Object and not a JsonString